# How to count all items in the cells of a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Can someone please help me with my Google Sheet? Basically, I need it to count all the items INCLUDING THE REPEATED ONES IN THE CELLS. As of right now, it's not taking them into account. I've marked the wrong results red.

I'm using COUNTIF and COUNTIFS functions. Perhaps there are some other better options.
Any help is appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lDB0eSt7J5fUFnDm0QuBv-ampXN8NTWN0ofBVqj9TQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: COUNTIFS counts how many **cells** meet your condition. You got 2 values in **same cell**, but they are being counted only as 1. Cell B7= `"Mini Notebook Pink
+ Mini Notebook Blue"` Separate those values into 2 different cells

Comment: In addition to the comment above, the formula you're using to count the instances of "Notebook cover" is "contains 'notebook cover' and does not contain 'mini'" -- this will fail if you have a cell like "Notebook Cover Purple + Mini Notebook Pink". You need to separate each value into a different cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,B$2:B$20),"+"),"(?:Purple|Blue|Pink|Green)","")),D2))
```

Note that I altered the D-columns values a bit so they would actually match those values in B-column.

Comment: Very well thought. I took the liberty and expanded your formula. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! 
But could you please tell me what should be done to the formula if the stats and orders are in different sheets?
Link to the altered spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lDB0eSt7J5fUFnDm0QuBv-ampXN8NTWN0ofBVqj9TQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You just have to alter the `#REF` error to include the correct reference. It's really basic GS stuff to be honest @Earthlien. Remove the error while inside your formula, then go to the tab with the data and select the appropriate range. GS will automatically correct it to reference the sheet too.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, @JvdV! I'm pretty new to this stuff. Just trying to glean this GS stuff :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The very nice formula in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423131/1527780) given by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv), needs to be dragged down for the rest of the list.

**Expanding the formula**

You could further expand by trying the following in cell `G1`

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,B:B),"+"),"(?:Purple|Blue|Pink|Green)","")))),
            "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1<>''
             group by Col1 label count(Col1) 'QTY' ",1)
```

[image]

**PROS**

1. **A single self-expanding formula for all present and all future products**
2. All products become alphabetised
3. There is no need for the extra column `D` where to manually write all products. This way you **avoid human errors**.

**CONS**

1. The fact that all products are accounted for will be a problem if you want just some of them -like just the notebooks-

Comment: Oh, wow! That is quite handy. Thank you! But is it possible to avoid the alphabetization (it's not wished for in my case, unfortunately)? 
And what should be done to your formula if the stats and orders are in different sheets?
Link to the altered spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lDB0eSt7J5fUFnDm0QuBv-ampXN8NTWN0ofBVqj9TQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array that has just one line in each element.
Then you can use the `Filter` function.

To create the array:

```
split(textjoin(char(10),true,B:B),char(10))
```

Then, to filter and count:

```
=counta(filter(split(textjoin(char(10),true,B:B),char(10)),isnumber(find("Mini Notebook",split(textjoin(char(10),true,B:B),char(10)))),not(isnumber(find("cover",split(textjoin(char(10),true,B:B),char(10)))))))
```

You can use similar logic for the other rows.

Note that `Find` is case sensitive. If you don't want that behavior, use `Search`.